How to sum comlum values in datatable using where condition
I am using MySQL to sum data then display it in datatable but since database is bigger it became very slow I am trying a new approach where I use client side to do calculation, tried every code I could find but keep getting this error :
$(...).DataTable(...).column(...).data(...).sum is not a function

I need to sum all values of column(5) where column(1) value = column(2) value

There is no "sum" in Datatables.
If I use the documentation, you have a footer callback
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html
Something like this
const $myTable = new DataTable('#example', {
  footerCallback: (row, data, start, end, display) => {
    let api = this.api();

    // Get the data for columns 1, 2, and 5
    let column1Data = api.column(1).data();
    let column2Data = api.column(2).data();
    let column5Data = api.column(5).data();

    // Total over all pages (column 5 where column 1 = column 2)
    let total = column1Data
      .map((value, index) => value == column2Data[index] ? +column5Data[index] || 0 : 0)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    // Total over this page (visible page)
    let pageTotal = displayedRows
      .map(index => column1Data[index] == column2Data[index] ? +column5Data[index] || 0 : 0)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
      '$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)'
    );
  }
});

